# How to filter out POST requests in fiddler by Body?

Tags: windows, post, fiddler

Using Fiddler.

Im listening only traffic from eg

**superhost.org**

which is added to my filters (eg via "**Show only if URL contains**").

Traffic consists of similar POST requests, which could be different only by Body.
Example:

First request:

```
{
  "param 1" : "1"
  "param 2" : "2"
}
```

Second request:

```
{
  "param 1" : "1"
  "param 2" : "3"
}
```

All headers etc same, only body differs.

Question:
How i can listen(simply saying - see in Requests list in Fiddler) for only requests, which has **"param 2" : "3"** in body.
(**So, in our fakeExample, Request1 should be filtered out, and only Request2 should be listened by Fiddler**)

Comment: By "listened" you mean displayed in the request/response list?

Comment: @Robert : in Requests list, which we see in Fiddler in left part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using Fiddler.Script, that reads the body, checks if it contains the string and if it finds the string hides the complete request/response:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("superhost.org")) {
        var body = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        if (!body.Contains("\"param 2\" : \"3\"")) {
            oSession["ui-hide"] = "does not have search string";
        }
    }
}
```

For an more advanced version you could check the path and/or content-type of the request before and then parse it to JSON so that formatting changes do not affect the recognition of the value you are searching.